# Dynamic equality for java objects

Tags: java, set, comparator

Suppose I have a `Person` class with simple attributes as name, age, address, phone and email.

I have a bunch of `Sets` each containing `Person` objects.

I would like to dynamically define `Set` specific equality for each set, in order to remove duplicates elegantly.

For Instance: I want one set to remove duplicate Persons based on phone and the other set to remove duplicate person objects with email.

The only way I am aware of is to sub class `Person` many times and override equals based on my requirement, but that would lead to explosion in number of classes.

This is allowed in case of `Comparators`. I can define as many anonymous comparators for the same object as I require/want.

Specifically I want to understand why in `Java` we can only have one definition for equality for an object but can define multiple comparators?

What would be the best way in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a Map instead of a Set? The map's key determines the attribute on which uniqueness is defined, and the map's values are a collection of unique-by-key objects.

Answer (score -1):

I would write like a DublicateRemover class. These class would contain the logic for removing dublicates for specific fields. for example:

```
public class DublicateRemover{
 public static Set<Person> removeDublicateByPhone(Set<Person> persons, Set<Person> persons2) {
  ...
 }
 public static Set<Person> removeDublicateByName(Set<Person> persons, Set<Person> persons2) {
  ...
 }

}
```